# Implicit Wait in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework, implicitwait

I am using below code to implement implicit wait in robot framework in PyCharm , it does not seem to work.

```
*** Settings ***
Resource        resource.robot
Test Setup      open admin portal url
Test Teardown   Close Browser Session
Library     Collections
Library     SeleniumLibrary


*** Test Cases ***


Usergroup Creation

    Login       ${username}   ${validpassword}
    Create Group

*** Keywords ***
Create Group
    #Set Selenium Implicit Wait          10 seconds
    Sleep               3
    Click Element       xpath://span[contains(text(),'User Groups')]

    Click Element       xpath://*[@class='row']/div[2]/div/a[1]/i[1]

    Input Text          id:displayName      TestGroup2
    Double Click Element    xpath://span[contains(text(),'suraj.morye@forcepoint.com')]
    Click Element       xpath://button[contains(text(),'Confirm')]

    Click Element       xpath://button[contains(text(),'Save')]

    Wait Until Page Contains        User Group created
```

I tried multiple library and stuff but to no use.

Answer (score 1):

To add implicit wait in robot framework we need to add,
Sleep 3s